# ~ operator in Mvc-5

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I know this question has been asked number of times but I am unabe to make out from the answers given earlier. I am trying to set the background image for all the views in _layout.cshtml file. 
I have tried two versions for the same 
1)    body style="background-image: Url('~/Content/Texture.png');"
 It tries to look at this path 
http://localhost/SU-Tour/~/Content/Texture.png 
whereas it should look into http://localhost/SU-Tour/Content/Texture.png
I am guessing it is not recognizing the tilde character.

2)    body style="background-image: @Url.Content("~/Content/Texture.png");"
This method doesn't create any error but the image property is not set to the body tag when i inspect the element under chrome.I am clueless about this one.

Please help me resolve this.

Comment: The tilde works without `Url.Content` in some circumstances (I think starting in MVC4). So you can use it in things like scripts, stylesheets, or img tags - `<img src="~/content/myimage.png">` will get rendered properly. But it looks like it doesn't work for CSS URLs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
style="background-image: url('@Url.Content("~/Content/Texture.png")');"
```

So that it ends up as:

```
style="background-image: url('/SU-Tour/Content/Texture.png');"
```

It can get a bit confusing when you start mixing Razor with CSS.

Comment: You don't need the quotes inside `url()` in CSS, so you can just do: `style="background-image: url(@Url.Content("~/Content/Texture.png"))"`, which makes it a little easier to read.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Force of habit really.

Comment: Thanks Lloyd..Works like a charm..It will be great if anybody can point me to a article explaining path scenarios in Razor .